# RSS feed, increase number of article displayed

Tags: joomla-3.x, rss

Currently my default rss feed displays just 5 articles 
http://www.newdle.it/granditemi.feed

is it possible to increase this number? Is there an option in the backend or should i edit the component?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the global configuration. There is a "Default Feed Limit" parameter. Chances are high this is set to 5 :)

Comment: Hi, i've already tried that but unfortunately is set to 100 but nothing changes. Is there some sort of cache?

Comment: There is a cache if you have that enabled. However in your case I would start looking for an option in the component where the feed is created. You're using K2 there? Then look there.

Comment: ok! I found it! it was on the configuration of k2. I've another question.. is it possible to specify different values for each feed?

Comment: Only if there is such an option in the component or the respective menu item.

Comment: If you have different feeds to manage, you can have a look to Obrss http://foobla.com/joomla/obrss